# How to insert image into strapi article?

Tags: strapi

I'm beginner of strapi, nodejs headless cms framework.

I've followed quick [start guide of official document](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html). I've created gatsby-blog and it works.

After setup, I've created new article with uploaded image, in the middle of article. (Not the image field in the Slug section) In the strapi admin page, I can find my new image in the media library list.

[image: insert-image-into-article-capture]

But when I open my strapi client in browser, the image is not shown. The source of image seems to the file path of backend server. I can find the image file on the backend/public/uploads folder. But it returns 404 error.

[image]

So, What am I missing of strapi setting? I've searched a lot but I can't find similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the field is public in your Strapi admin dashboard.

Beyond that, it seems like the src tag in your screenshot has a relative url - if you are not hosting the backend on the same path as the frontend, I would suspect you have to prepend the backend base path :-)